# Find a polar equation for the curve of the given Cartesian equations: $y=x$, $4y^2 = x$ and $xy=4$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am asked to find a polar equation for the curve of the given Cartesian equations: $y=x$, $4y^2 = x$ and $xy=4$.

What I got here so far is

$$
y = x\\
r \sin(\theta) = r \cos(\theta)\\
\boxed{\tan(\theta) = 1}
$$

$$
4y^2=x\\
4r^2 \sin^2(\theta) = r \cos(\theta)\\
\boxed{r = \frac{\cot(\theta)\cdot \csc(\theta)}{4}}
$$

$$
xy = 4\\
r^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) = 4\\
\boxed{r^2 = \frac{8}{\sin(2 \theta)}}
$$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: $\tan\theta = 1 \iff \theta = \pi/4 \lor \theta = 5\pi/4$ in $[0,2\pi[$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all correct. The first equation has no $r$, only $\theta$ since it is a straight line through origin at $45^0.$